# Why is MySQL slow when using LIMIT in my query?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I'm trying to figure out why is one of my query slow and how I can fix it but I'm a bit puzzled on my results.

I have an `orders` table with around 80 columns and 775179 rows and I'm doing the following request :

`SELECT * FROM orders WHERE id_state = 2 AND id_mp IS NOT NULL ORDER BY creation_date DESC LIMIT 200`

which returns 38 rows in 4.5s

When removing the `ORDER BY` I'm getting a nice improvement :

`SELECT * FROM orders WHERE id_state = 2 AND id_mp IS NOT NULL LIMIT 200`

38 rows in 0.30s

But when removing the `LIMIT` without touching the `ORDER BY` I'm getting an even better result :

`SELECT * FROM orders WHERE id_state = 2 AND id_mp IS NOT NULL ORDER BY creation_date DESC`

38 rows in 0.10s (??)

Why is my LIMIT so hungry ?

**GOING FURTHER**

I was trying a few things before sending my answer and after noticing that I had an index on `creation_date` (which is a `datetime`) I removed it and the first query now runs in 0.10s. Why is that ?

**EDIT**

Good guess, I have indexes on the others columns part of the where.

```
mysql> explain SELECT * FROM orders WHERE id_state = 2 AND id_mp IS NOT NULL ORDER BY creation_date DESC LIMIT 200;
+----+-------------+--------+-------+------------------------+---------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table  | type  | possible_keys          | key        | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+------------------------+---------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | orders | index | id_state_idx,id_mp_idx | creation_date | 5       | NULL | 1719 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+------------------------+---------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

1 row in set (0.00 sec)

```
mysql> explain SELECT * FROM orders WHERE id_state = 2 AND id_mp IS NOT NULL ORDER BY creation_date DESC;
+----+-------------+--------+-------+------------------------+-----------+---------+------+-------+----------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table  | type  | possible_keys          | key       | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra                                              |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+------------------------+-----------+---------+------+-------+----------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | orders | range | id_state_idx,id_mp_idx | id_mp_idx | 3       | NULL | 87502 | Using index condition; Using where; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+------------------------+-----------+---------+------+-------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Because after the first query, the results were (partially) cached for the following queries...

Comment: This is not the case, re-running the same queries are giving me consistent results

Comment: Maybe your server is slow....

Comment: if you are doing performance test and you have cache, you should use SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE in your queries, then its not using the cache. Also, provide a explain statement, maybe some indexes are missing on the datetime column.

Comment: @KayNelson : the `explain` is indeed very helpful

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Indexes do not necessarily improve performance.  To better understand what is happening, it would help if you included the `explain` for the different queries.

My best guess would be that you have an index in `id_state` or even `id_state, id_mp` that can be used to satisfy the `where` clause.  If so, the first query without the `order by` would use this index.  It should be pretty fast.  Even without an index, this requires a sequential scan of the pages in the `orders` table, which can still be pretty fast.

Then when you add the index on `creation_date`, MySQL decides to use that index instead for the `order by`.  This requires reading each row in the index, then fetching the corresponding data page to check the `where` conditions and return the columns (if there is a match).  This reading is highly inefficient, because it is not in "page" order but rather as specified by the index.  Random reads can be quite inefficient.

Worse, even though you have a `limit`, you still have to read the *entire* table because the entire result set is needed.  Although you have saved a sort on 38 records, you have created a massively  inefficient query.

By the way, this situation gets significantly worse if the `orders` table does not fit in available memory.  Then you have a condition called "thrashing", where each new record tends to generate a new I/O read.  So, if a page has 100 records on it, the page might have to be read 100 times.

You can make all these queries run faster by having an index on `orders(id_state, id_mp, creation_date)`.  The `where` clause will use the first two columns and the `order by` will use the last.

Comment: Great answer, but on a table of 775179 records i would say indexes is needed right?

Comment: @KayNelson . . . Yes.  That is why I suggest a better index in the final paragraph.  I wanted to be a little careful, because without the `explain` the answer is all speculation.

Comment: Yes that is very true!

Comment: Good guess, I edited my question. Now why is MySQL changing it's index when adding the LIMIT? It should be faster if it used the `id_mp_idx` index on the first query isn't it ?

Comment: @AlexandreJacob . . . I cannot speak specifically to how MySQL chooses among different plans.  I would guess that somewhere there is the assumption:  "hey, if the query has `limit`, then it is returning just a few rows and doing the ordering using the index is the better option".  The alternative is to produce the entire result set, and then order that.

Comment: @AlexandreJacob If you wonder why MySQL uses indexes sometimes and sometimes doesn't, it's because it won't use indexes with too low cardinality.

Comment: Thank you it helped me a lot. using `IGNORE INDEX (creation_date)` on the first query makes it as fast as the second, creating an index `test_idx` on id_state_idx + id_mp_idx and adding `USE INDEX (test_idx)` to the query makes it very efficient (< 0.01s)

Comment: Now my is SP is loading in 1s instead of 28s. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

Same problem happened in my project,
I did some test, and found out that LIMIT is slow because of row lookups

See:
[MySQL ORDER BY / LIMIT performance: late row lookups](https://explainextended.com/2009/10/23/mysql-order-by-limit-performance-late-row-lookups/)

So, the solution is:

(A)when using LIMIT, select not all columns, but only the PK columns

(B)Select all columns you need, and then join with the result set of (A)

SQL should likes:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    orders O1   <=== this is what you want
JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            ID                         <== fetch the PK column only, this should be fast
        FROM
            orders
        WHERE
            [your query condition]     <== filter record by condition
        ORDER BY
            [your order by condition]  <== control the record order
        LIMIT 2000, 50                 <== filter record by paging condition
    ) as O2
ON
    O1.ID = O2.ID
ORDER BY
    [your order by condition]          <== control the record order
```

in my DB,

the old SQL which select all columns using "LIMIT 21560, 20", costs about 4.484s.

the new sql costs only 0.063s. The new one is about 71 times faster

Comment: original query was slow 2.5s if i select only PK it is 1.5s bit faster but still slow (myisam, order by some column - index) and just using limit offset deeply in the data eg LIMIT 99990, 10

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue on a table of 2.5 million records. Removing the limit part the query took a few seconds. With the limit part it stuck forever.

I solved with a subquery. In your case it would became:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT * 
     FROM orders 
     WHERE id_state = 2 
       AND id_mp IS NOT NULL 
     ORDER BY creation_date DESC) tmp 
LIMIT 200
```

I noted that the original query was fast when the number of selected rows was greater than the limit parameter. Se the query became extremely slow when the limit parameter was useless.

---

Another solution is trying forcing index. In your case you can try with

```
SELECT * 
FROM orders force index (id_mp_idx) 
WHERE id_state = 2 
  AND id_mp IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY creation_date DESC 
LIMIT 200
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that mysql is forced to sort data on the fly. My query of deep offset like:

```
ORDER BY somecol LIMIT 99990, 10
```

Took 2.5s.

I fixed it by creating a new table, which has presorted data by column somecol and contains only ids, and there the deep offset (without need to use ORDER BY) takes 0.09s.

0.1s is not still enough fast though. 0.01s would be better.

I will end up creating a table that holds the page number as special indexed column, so instead of doing limit x, y i will query where page = Z.

i just tried it and it is fast as 0.0013. only problem is, that the offseting is based on static numbers (presorted in pages by 10 items for example.. its not that big problem though.. you can still get out any data of any pages.)